# What are the favourable conditions for the formation of porphyry copper deposits?

Tags: geology, geochemistry, economic-geology, ore

Favourable condition for the formation of porphyry copper deposits is :
1. Extremely low oxygen fugacity in initial magma
2. High water content in initial magma
3. Crystallization of magama at deep crustal level
4. Crystallization of magama at earth's surface

Comment: Looks like an exam question...

Comment: Yes, saw it in a question paper. Only one answer is correct

Comment: Exam questions are better received if you show what you have tried to answer the question yourself.